# Excluding root of directory from Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am using ASP.Net forms authentication to secure a directory called "pro". This is all working fine, however what we want to do is to exclude the root page within the directory - basically this is a sales page detailing the benefits of registering.

So, my question is whether it is possible to secure a directory, but exclude a particular page within that directory?

The other option, which seems pretty easy but not particularly tidy in terms of the file system is to structure my directories like:

```
/pro/
/pro/default.aspx
/pro/ (secure anything within this folder)
/pro/loggedin/page1.aspx
/pro/loggedin/page2.aspx
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow particular page, then it will be like..

```
<location path="PageName.aspx">
 <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>               
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad - yes, but not if this page is within the directory I have secured....that wont work...

Comment: You can put the pages that you want to secure in some other folder and put other pages in some other directories.

Comment: Ok - I was hoping that the location path would support some type of regex to exclude a file, but if not then your answer will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To protect a folder, try the following:

```
<location path="/pro">
   <system.web>
        <authorization>
             <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: You cannot use directories with the path attribute. Instead you just override the setting with a web.config inside the folder you want to change the settings on.